sscanf returns 0 when run in CIL
I have this IL code from Expert .NET 2.0 IL Assembler by Serge Lidin:
This is in a file called CilTest.il:
//----------- Program header
.assembly extern  mscorlib { auto }
.assembly OddOrEven  { }
.module OddOrEven.exe
//----------- Class declaration
.namespace Odd.or {
    .class public auto ansi Even extends [mscorlib]System.Object {
//----------- Field declaration
        .field public static int32 val
//----------- Method declaration
        .method public static void check( ) cil managed {
            .entrypoint
            .locals init (int32 Retval)
        AskForNumber:
            ldstr "Enter a number"
            call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine (string)
            call string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine ()
            ldsflda valuetype CharArray8 Format
            ldsflda int32 Odd.or.Even::val
            call vararg int32 sscanf(string,int8*,...,int32*)
            stloc Retval
            ldloc Retval
            brfalse Error
            ldsfld int32 Odd.or.Even::val
            ldc.i4 1
            and
            brfalse ItsEven
            ldstr "odd!"
            br PrintAndReturn
        ItsEven:
            ldstr "even!"
            br PrintAndReturn
        Error:
            ldstr "How rude!"
        PrintAndReturn:
            call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine (string)
            ldloc Retval
            brtrue AskForNumber
            ret
        } // End of method
    } // End of class
} // End of namespace
//----------- Global items
.field public static valuetype CharArray8 Format at FormatData
//----------- Data declaration
.data FormatData = bytearray(25 64 00 00 00 00 00 00) // % d . . . . . .
//----------- Value type as placeholder
.class public explicit CharArray8 
              extends [mscorlib]System.ValueType { .size 8  }
//----------- Calling unmanaged code
.method public static pinvokeimpl("msvcrt.dll" cdecl) 
    vararg int32 sscanf(string,int8*) cil managed { }

The following file is in the same folder and called CilTest.ilproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Net.Sdk.il/7.0.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

I'm compiling the code using:
dotnet build -r win-x64 --self-contained -c release

When I run the code, I get this error:

It seems as though the call to sscanf returns 0 successful formatted strings:
call vararg int32 sscanf(string,int8*,...,int32*)

Why is sscanf() not working?
Is there a way to debug the code so I can see why sscanf() is not working?

What happens in less exotic environment, e.g. just a C-programmed executable? I ask because getting scanf wrong is so easy....

The first two parameters to sscanf are strings, not a string and an int.

This is the exact code by Serge Lidin who wrote the book, so it must work. Could it have something to do with using .NET Core instead of Framework?

Add keyword preservesig after cil managed, like this:
//----------- Calling unmanaged code
.method public static pinvokeimpl("msvcrt.dll" cdecl) 
    vararg int32 sscanf(string,int8*) cil managed preservesig { }

In .NET implementations later than 2.0 this keyword is required to indicate that the return value of the P/Invoke method has to be preserved.

I have limited experience but have always used the PInvoke method when calling sscanf in this manner. We used something along the lines of :
.method private pinvokeimpl("msvcrt.dll" cdec1)
    int32 sscanf _pinvoke(string, int8*)
cil; managed { }

You can also just write your own version of sscanf(MSVC)(GLIBC), as it's a relatively simple function and incorporate that into your program.

Do you think it has something to do with using .NET Core? This is the example from the book so I assume the code is correct.
